# "Notes by Ajay" is grammatically correct?

Tags: prepositions

I am little confused on usage of "by", so below sentence is grammatically correct ?

> Notes by Ajay.

I am going to start a blog, the website name I came up as `notesbyajay.com`, However my friend suggested that this was incorrect and it should be "Notes from Ajay".

Here, Notes - Pages/Blogs on technical articles created by me.

Comment: I've answered, but can you explain why you doubt this to be incorrect?  Why are you confused by "by"? What has confused you?

Comment: Blogs are usually in the first person so I would not use that tag for your blog.

Comment: @JamesK - I got confused when my friend suggest like - `notesFromAjay` looks more correct, but I liked notesbyAjay

Comment: As an aside "Notes by Ajay" is not a sentence.  A sentence is something that has at least a subject and a main verb.

Comment: Also, correct question structure is **Is "Notes by Ajay" grammatically correct?**

Comment: Aside: please do not post the same question twice. Readers are trying to close the [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/327285/notes-by-ajay-is-grammatically-correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a "sentence" because there is no verb.  But the implied meaning "These are notes by Ajay" has no errors.  "Notes *from* Ajay" has exactly the same grammatical structure and is equally correct (but with the meaning of "from" instead of "by".)

Answer (score 0):

"By" is probably the most typical preposition to indicate authorship. "Notes by Ajay" suggests that Ajay wrote the notes. "By" can also be used for other forms of creative work, and many business names follow the pattern "PRODUCT by NAME" ("Cakes by Ajay" for a bakery, "Hair by Ajay" for a hair salon, etc.).